# Moonbeam (polkadot parachain) transaction error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, polkadot

I have an issue setting up local node.

There is a docker-compose which launches Kusama network with some minor changes (like epoch time and proposal voting/enacting time) with custom chain-spec for 6 validators, and it runs with 2 collator nodes of moonbeam (default moonbeam-local chain-spec, where Alice and Bob addresses replaced with custom ones).

I successfully launch the parachain on relay chain, and it produces blocks (besides, it triggers something like "Skipping because we are not eligible", not sure if it is ok, but still, the blocks are being produced). Btw, I've manually set all the session keys for the validators and collators, sending the RPC calls (for the collators it's only nmbs???). I can connect to metamask,

I can query some info through RPC, etc. But the problem is that I cannot send any transactions, it all fails with the following error:

`ValueError: {'code': -32603, 'message': 'submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::Call))'}.`

The same transation works on moonbase testnet, and it also works with --dev collator. What could be the issue? Thank you in advance

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node_david:
    ports:
      - "30333:30333"
      - "9933:9933"
      - "9944:9944"
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_david --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeDavid --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1

  node_daniel:
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_daniel --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeDaniel --bootnodes '/ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp'  -ldebug
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2

  node_jack:
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_jack --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeJack --bootnodes '/ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp'
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.3

  node_john:
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_john --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeJohn --bootnodes '/ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp'
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.4

  node_judy:
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_judy --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeJudy --bootnodes '/ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp'
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5

  node_max:
    image: kusama-custom:0.9.5
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
    command: polkadot --chain=/kusama-custom.json --base-path /tmp/node_max --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --rpc-cors all --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --name NodeMax --bootnodes '/ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp'
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.6

  para_daniel:
    image: purestake/moonbeam:v0.11.2
    depends_on:
      - node_daniel
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
      - ../chain-specs/moonbeam.json:/moonbeam.json
    command: --collator --log debug --chain ./moonbeam.json --base-path /tmp/para_daniel --name "CollatorDaniel" --force-authoring --parachain-id 2000 --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods Unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 -- --execution wasm --chain /kusama-custom.json
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.2.1

  para_david:
    image: purestake/moonbeam:v0.11.2
    depends_on:
      - node_david
    volumes:
      - ../chain-specs/kusama-custom.json:/kusama-custom.json
      - ../chain-specs/moonbeam.json:/moonbeam.json
    command: --collator --chain ./moonbeam.json --base-path /tmp/para_david --name "CollatorDavid" --force-authoring --parachain-id 2000 --rpc-cors all --rpc-methods Unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --unsafe-rpc-external --bootnodes /ip4/172.28.2.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp -- --execution wasm --chain /kusama-custom.json --bootnodes /ip4/172.28.1.1/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
    networks:
      testing_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.2.2

networks:
  testing_net:
    #    driver_opts:
    #      com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4: 172.28.0.1
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```